# what is the return value of getsession.insert in ace editor?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, ace-editor

The documentation for ace editor is not very clear on what the return value is for these two functions in editsession:
addmarker
insert

[edit session api ref](http://ace.c9.io/#nav=api&api=edit_session)

the addmarker is not actually adding a marker for me, and the insert is not inserting any lines in the editor. Which is why i thought i should inspect the return values.

Can anyone tell me what the return values are supposed to contain in each case?
For insert, i dont get any return value.
For addmarker, i get a row number and a column number. For example, row number 2 and column number 550.
What is the meaning of this? What information are the return values giving me?

I am storing the edit session in a scope variable(I'm using angularjs)
So my commands look something like this:

```
        var addmarker_ret_value = $scope.aceSession3.addMarker(
            new range(row_1, 0, row_2, 0), "ace_active-line", "fullLine"
        );
var position = {};
position['row'] = row_val;
position['col'] = col_val;
var ret_value = $scope.aceSession3.insert(position,line_content);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

addMarker returns markerId which can be used to remove marker later,
insert returns the position of the end of inserted text

here's a simple example that inserts string "text" at row 1 column 0, and highlights inserted text for one second.

```
position = {row : 1, column: 0}
endPosition = session.insert(position, "text")
var Range = require("ace/range").Range
markerId = session.addMarker(
    Range.fromPoints(position, endPosition), "ace_highlight-marker"
)
setTimeout(function() {
   session.removeMarker(markerId)
}, 1000)
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know if the marker still works if the position and endposition are the same, or if they differ only by 1?
for example, i am not able to see the marker if endposition = startposition + 1.

Comment: Markers should work for one character ranges but not for empty ones.
`endposition = startposition + 1` won't work since positions are not numbers, or do you mean `endposition.column = startposition.column + 1`?

Comment: yes. something like that. `startposition.row = x, endposition.row = parseInt(x) + 1`;
Do you know i could highlight a single line in ace editor? The above mentioned code will highlight both startRow and endRow, if endRow is the row after startRow. If i give startposition.row = endposition.row, i don't get a single line marker at all.

Comment: never mind. figured it out. For someone wanting to highlight only a single line in ace editor, specify the type parameter as `line`, instead of specifying it as `fullLine` or leaving it blank.